# Calling a library from within a view

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have a library for managing error/success messages. I am autoloading the library from the Base Controller with `use App\Libraries\Messages;` and `$this->messages = new Messages() ;` in `initController`
Throughout the various controllers I am using the messages class without issue. However, in my view, I can't access the substantiated class.

I'm used to the CI3 methodology `$CI = get_instance(); echo $CI->messages->show() ;` but of course this approach is now out of date.

I have tried adding the following method to app/Config/Routes.php

```
     public static function messages($getShared = true)
     {
         if ($getShared) {
             return static::getSharedInstance('messages');
         }
    
         return new \App\Libraries\Messages();
     }
```

and in the view

```
$Messages = \Config\Services::messages() ;
```

That created $Messages as a null.

Answer (score 0):

With Codeigniter 4 you can literally call your `Messages` library in your View in the same way you do your controllers.

```
use App\Libraries\Messages;

later ....

$messages = new Messages();
```

In your view will achieve what you're after.

Ah so you mean you want to access the actual instance. In which case you would pass it to your view ....

```
view('file',['Messages'=>$this->messagesObj]);

And you can then call in the view ...

$Messages->function()
```

But it does mean that updates may not revert back ... The other option would be to use a Session variable and update that which is also available across all areas.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. Using "new $Messages" invoked the constructor which reinitialised the session variable. 
What I hadn't thought of is adding a parameter to the constructor ...
public function __constructor(bool $reinitialize = true)

$messages

Comment: Editing a posted comment isn't easy :-(
What I wanted to say in my previous comment was that the Messages class is being initialised in BaseController. It is that particular instance I want to access, using `new Messages` in the view gives me a brand new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I wanted was Services.

To start off I needed this in app/Config/Services.php

```
    public static function Messages($getShared = true)
    {
        if ($getShared) {
            return static::getSharedInstance('Messages');
        }
        return new \App\Libraries\Messages();
    }
```

In BaseController implement the library with :

```
var $messages ;
...
function __construct()
{
  $this->messages = \Config\Services::Messages();
}
```

This allows me to use $this->messages throughout the controllers. When it comes time to use the Messages library in a view, it's as simple as

```
$Messages = \Config\Services::Messages();
```

That gives me the object implemented in BaseController :-)

Thank you @Antony for your assistance :)